# How do you classify books by genre (using deep learning) when some books have multiple genres?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, text-classification

I am trying to build a neural network that looks at the text of a book and guesses the book's genre. I can train a network fine when each book only has one genre. Is there a good way to train a network when a book is associated with multiple genres?

I have tried using a basic SGDClassifier from sklearn. It works wonderfully with a data set where each one book/block of text is tied to one genre. Unfortunately, I do not know how to give it a data set where each book/block of text is associated with multiple genres.

Here is the basic code I am using for context:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

sgd = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),

                ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),

                ('clf', SGDClassifier('basic parameters')),

               ])

sgd.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = sgd.predict(x_test)
```

Does anyone know of a good way to approach this problem? Can anyone link me to a place where a smart person has already solved it?

Comment: The idea is not to ask "which genre is Twilight" but "Is Twilight horror? Is Twilight romance? Is Twilight literature?" A neural network could give you all the answers at the same time (or you can use a bunch of binary classifiers if you already know how to use those and don't want to mess with NNs).

Comment: The term you're looking for is "multilabel classification", so you can find good examples by googling this term. Here's one from Kaggle, actually very similar because it looks at genres: https://www.kaggle.com/jyothish/ways-to-solve-a-multilabel-classification-problem

Comment: Having said that, you should know that Stack Overflow is for programming, not for machine learning at that level. You should visit Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com), which is the site for statistics, machine learning, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question should be asked on stats.stackexchange.com but I'll try to answer nonetheless. What you have here is a multilabel "classification problem". Say you have 3 genres A, B and C what you  can do is consider each combination of these 3 genres a class and you will get the following classes [0 0 0], [1 0 0], [0 1 0], [0 0 1], [1 1 0], [1 0 1], [0 1 1]. [1 1 1] with [1 0 1] for example being a book that is A and C.

These links should help you understand and deal with your problem

https://towardsdatascience.com/journey-to-the-center-of-multi-label-classification-384c40229bff
https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-classification-and-class-activation-map-on-fashion-mnist-1454f09f5925